# style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat not found

Tags: android

I had a power cut, and after opening the android studio, I get this error every time I open android studio, my files- all of them are affected by this.how to fix it?

```
Error:resource style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat (akacom.example.patta.avoid:style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat) not found.
Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> Failed to execute aapt

Comment: show me your catlog or error msg

Comment: catlog? or logcat? .. i have edited the "message" which i get every time i open android studio

Comment: sry for my mistake but in your `style.xml` you added this style : `<style name="Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat" >` ?

Comment: <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

Comment: this is your default `style` and error is you don't create custom `style` which u call other `xml` or `java` file so first u create custom `style` as i put in my answer and after that u call this `style` any where  you want

Comment: it's happening with every project, on startup. i cant rebuild the project or clean it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165317/discussion-between-mohammad-ali-and-ravi-kilnake).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved this with going to my app:gradle updating my compilesdk to 27
and compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'

along with maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } to my project:gradle under all projects

Comment: If you had an appcompat dependency before and it compiled before the power cut, it is possible that your gradle cache got corrupted. If that's the case, try manually deleting the gradle cache (~/.gradle) and using the previous version of appcompat to confirm.

Comment: please guide me, the problem is still present whenever I open a new project

Comment: Did you try invalidating the cache and deleting the ~/.gradle directory?